# ASP.NET MVC 3 Model Binding - ViewBag.Title clash with input of id="Title"

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-binding, viewbag, name-clash

There seems to be an issue with the ViewBag dynamic properties.  Lets say I have:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = @Model.CourseName;
}
```

And then in a form on the page I have:

```
@Html.TextBox("Title", null, new {style="width:400px;"})
```

Where Title is the name of a field in a database table.

When the page first opens, text box with an id of "Title" takes the value of the ViewBag.Title dynamic property.

I am a bit hazy on the exact details of Model Binding, but this does seem to be a bug, or if not, if it is something that occurs naturally as a result of the binding process, then it would be nice to be warned of this.

The work around I found, was to rename the ViewBag property to:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Titulo = @Model.CourseName;
}
```

(Title changed to Titulo - Always good to know another language to avoid name clashes...)

And the issue went away.

However, the question is:

Is this behaviour to be expected?  The bug was easy to find (took an hour to figure it out, including writing this question), but I suspect that other bugs might be more, uhmmm, recondite.

### EDIT:

**Rephrasing the question:**

Does the Model Binder automatically bind properties it finds in the ViewBag?  Even when an existing property exists in the strongly typed ViewModel I have passed to the page?  Surely the ViewModel should take preference?

Comment: Can a naming convention be called a bug ;o)

Comment: Ardman:  I didn't call it a bug, I called it an issue.  It was a bug in my code to not realise how the Model binder treats the ViewBag properties.  See my Edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Html.TextBox checks `ViewData`/`ViewBag` values first, then `Model`. To make sure it takes `Model` value, you must use `Html.TextBoxFor`.

Comment: Great answer. Quick comment. Though Html.TextBoxFor will work in this case, beware ListBoxFor and DropDownListFor extension methods which still check for the value in the ViewBag before the Model.