# Why I'm getting some text in Model member?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

When I go to Create view I pass name, for one text.

```
public ActionResult AddItem(int id, string name)
{
    ViewBag.Name = name;

    return View();
}
```

I passed name to new View:

```
@Html.ActionLink("add", "AddItem", "Items", new { id = item.ItemID, name = item.Name }, null)
```

I want to use item.Name for one text, but I see it here:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
```

What I do wrong? I don't understand how this name applied to new item???

Comment: You setting a `ViewBag` property, not the model property.

Comment: If I delete this name = item.Name from new { id = item.ItemID, name = item.Name }. Everything ok!!
ViewBag.Name = name; if I delete this, nothing changes I see pass data

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4375323/binding-conflict-between-a-property-named-title-in-my-model-and-view-title-in-my and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5103889/asp-net-mvc-3-model-binding-viewbag-title-clash-with-input-of-id-title